# (Friday Night Funkin') Problem when running "lime test windows"

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib, lime-haxe

Whenever I try to run "Lime test windows" I get greeted by a message that says:

"Error: Failed with error: No such Project : extension-webm.ndll"
even though extension-webm is installed in the haxelib library.

I am actively looking for the solution but if someone could help me that would be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

So it looks like I had installed extension-webm to the wrong path.

Fixing this was easy, first I ran "lime setup" (haxelib setup works too I think) in the command prompt and then added the path.

Then I installed extension-webm again and ran "lime rebuild extension-webm windows" in the command prompt.
Then "lime test windows" ran just fine.

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.